# Semantic use of <dl>, <dt>, <dd> for a price breakdown, or on list of items in a checkout

Tags: html, semantic-markup

Is correct (in the sense of semantic HTML) to use the `<dl>`, `<dt>`, `<dd>` tags to:

1. Show a price breakdown in a checkout page? Like the ones which show Subtotal, Taxes and Total.
2. To show the list of items for an order when the items have like a brief explanation of what they contain or what are they made of. For example, in a burguer checkout page if the customer has customised his/her order to add some extra ingredients or something like that.

I came across this while thinking how to mark up [this design](https://btholt.github.io/complete-intro-to-web-dev-v3/images/coffee_masters.png).

By reading the [spec](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/grouping-content.html#the-dl-element), it looks to me like it is inside the recommendations but, maybe I'm twisting a bit the semantics here?

I'd like to hear your understanding of the spec in this regard.